# Why is GetClientRect including the window border and title bar?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screenshot

I'm writing some code that will take a screenshot of another application, given its' window handle, in C++. The method I am using is to use `BitBlt`. My application is successfully taking the screenshot and I have a function that will save that image data out to a bmp file.

The screenshot contains the window's chrome though. That is, the border and the title bar. Based on my understanding, `GetClientRect` is supposed to exclude the window's border and title bar. I understand that `GetWindowRect` returns the coordinates within the user's desktop, and `GetClientRect` returns the coordinates relative to the application itself.

I notice in my screenshots that the title bar and left border are visible, but the right border and bottom of the application are cut off. So, I'm thinking that if I want to exclude the title and borders then I need to be doing some sort of combination of `GetWindowRect` and `GetClientRect`, and using information about the window itself to offset the `GetClientRect` dimensions by whatever the height of the window's title bar is, for example.

Does this sound accurate, or is my code below doing something wrong?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "ScreenshotManager.h"

namespace Managers {

    ScreenshotManager::ScreenshotManager(HWND gameHandle) {

        // get a device context for the window
        m_gameContext = GetWindowDC(gameHandle);

        // create a compatible device context for bitblt
        m_bitmapContext = CreateCompatibleDC(m_gameContext);

        // get window client area dimensions
        GetClientRect(gameHandle, &m_gameClientArea);

    }

    bool ScreenshotManager::TakeScreenshot() {

        // create a compatible bitmap for the game screenshots
        m_bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(m_gameContext, m_gameClientArea.right, m_gameClientArea.bottom);

        // select the bitmap into the compatible device context
        SelectObject(m_bitmapContext, m_bitmap);

        // perform bit block transfer
        if (BitBlt(m_bitmapContext, 0, 0, m_gameClientArea.right, m_gameClientArea.bottom, m_gameContext, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) == false)
            return false;

        // get information about the taken screenshot
        GetObject(m_bitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &m_bitmapInformation);

        return true;

    }

    void ScreenshotManager::SaveScreenshot(LPCWSTR outputPath) {

        BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;    
        BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

        bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bi.biWidth = m_bitmapInformation.bmWidth;
        bi.biHeight = m_bitmapInformation.bmHeight;
        bi.biPlanes = 1;    
        bi.biBitCount = 32;    
        bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
        bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
        bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
        bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
        bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
        bi.biClrImportant = 0;

        DWORD dwBmpSize = ((m_bitmapInformation.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * m_bitmapInformation.bmHeight;

        // Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that 
        // call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc 
        // have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
        HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND,dwBmpSize);
        char *lpbitmap = (char *)GlobalLock(hDIB);

        // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap and copies them into a buffer which is pointed to by lpbitmap.
        GetDIBits(m_gameContext, m_bitmap, 0, (UINT)m_bitmapInformation.bmHeight, lpbitmap, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

        // A file is created, this is where we will save the screen capture.
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(outputPath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);   

        // Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size
        DWORD dwSizeofDIB = dwBmpSize + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

        //Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
        bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 

        //Size of the file
        bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB; 

        //bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps
        bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; //BM   

        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
        WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
        WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
        WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

        //Unlock and Free the DIB from the heap
        GlobalUnlock(hDIB);    
        GlobalFree(hDIB);

        //Close the handle for the file that was created
        CloseHandle(hFile);

    }

}
```

Comment: `PrintWindow` could save you a bit of work, and works when it's minimized, too.

Comment: I ruled out the `PrintWindow` function because, based on the documentation, it sounds like it defers the actual processing of the screenshot generation off to the program that you're taking a screenshot of. Isn't that less compatible than the BitBlt method?

Comment: I haven't looked too far into it, but it does have the advantage of minimized windows. If you're concerned, you can check whether it's minimized in the `TakeScreenshot` function and pick which method to use.

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates are wrong?  Maybe the program is doing something weird.  Check with Spy++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GetClientRect()` does not include the border and title bar.  All it does is tell you the *dimensions* of the client area.

`BitBlt()` copies a rectangular region of pixels from one device context to another.  In this example the source DC is a *window* DC, so the origin coordinates are relative to that window.

What your code is doing is copying a *client*-sized rectangle from the *window*’s origin.  (That’s why the right and bottom edges go missing.)

You might be interested in `AdjustWindowRectEx()` to help identify the coordinates of the region you want to copy.

Comment: Nice answer. About your last statement, how would one use `AdjustWindowRectEx` to identify those coordinates?

Comment: AdjustWindowRectEx is for going the other direction, expaning a client rect to account for the non-client area (sometimes called the chrome).  One approach is the create a POINT (0, 0) and transform it with ClientToScreen.  The use GetWindowRect and compare the transformed point to the left and top of the window rect.  The difference will tell you how far to offset the source for your BitBlt.